# One-way synchronize with filter

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

So I have a central database (2008 R2). From this server I want to sync certain data to users devices (to a CE 3.5 database), this is a one-way sync and the data is read-only on the devices. Let's say that I have an image album application, and I want to be able to sync albums to the device.

The database contains many albums and images, so I don't want to sync all the albums to the users. Instead the user selects which albums he wants to sync to his/her device.

Database description:

[image: Database description]

So up until now this would work fine using the sync framework (2.1) with *parameter based filters* and provision the server database on the *NUM_ID* of the wanted Album as a scope.

Now in my application a lot of albums share images. And I want the users to be able to download several albums to their devices. And it's now I start getting problems with the sync framework. So it's no problem with adding another scope to the database.

But when I do a second sync to the local db it starts with removing all tracking tables created by the first sync. So the second sync kind of works, in the way that it downloads the data needed to look at the second album. However it doesn't compare any images already in the database, instead it just downloads all the images in the selected album. And let's say that about 80% of the images is shared, then much of the data is totally unnecessary.

So my question is, is there any way to configure the sync framework not to remove the tracking tables (or something that makes it work)?

Or should I maybe look at something else than the sync framework? ([@EricEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) has previously hinted about something called *SQL Server Merge Replication* could that be applicable for my application).

I would prefer using some kind of framework, so I don't have to create all the stored procedures and triggers etc in the database.

Here follows a part of the sync log, this is when syncing the second album (ie. one scope is already synced to the CE database).

```
VERBOSE, Connecting using string: Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=dt;User ID=**;Password=****
VERBOSE, Reading Schema Version Info
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [sync].[schema_info]
VERBOSE, Connecting using string: Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=dt;User ID=sync
INFO   , ----- Populating Scope Provisioning from Scope Description for '1027_SyncScope' -----
INFO   , Adding Table Provisioning for '[dt_album].[ALBUMS]'
INFO   , Adding Table Provisioning for '[dt_album].[ALBIMGLINKS]'
INFO   , Adding Table Provisioning for '[dt_album].[IMAGES]'
INFO   , --- END Populating Scope Provisioning from Scope Description for '1027_SyncScope' ---
VERBOSE, Connecting to database: TEstMC.sdf
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [schema_info]
VERBOSE, Connecting to database: TEstMC.sdf
VERBOSE, Connecting to database: TEstMC.sdf
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [schema_info]
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [schema_info]
INFO   , ----- Provisioning Scope '1027_SyncScope' on Database 'TEstMC.sdf' -----
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [schema_info]
INFO   , Dropping Tracking Table '[ALBUMS]'<------------------- WHY???
INFO   , Creating Tracking Table '[ALBUMS_tracking]'
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: CREATE TABLE [ALBUMS_tracking] ([NUM_ID] int NOT NULL, [sync_row_is_tombstone] int NOT NULL, [sync_update_peer_key] int NOT NULL, [sync_update_peer_timestamp] bigint NOT NULL, [sync_create_peer_key] int NOT NULL, [sync_create_peer_timestamp] bigint NOT NULL, [sync_update_bsn] bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, [last_change_datetime] datetime DEFAULT GETDATE() NULL)
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: ALTER TABLE [ALBUMS_tracking] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ALBUMS_tracking] PRIMARY KEY ([NUM_ID])
INFO   , Adding Change Tracking index to Tracking Table '[ALBUMS_tracking]'
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: CREATE INDEX sysChangeTxBsn_idx ON [ALBUMS_tracking] (sync_update_bsn);
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: SELECT [schema_major_version], [schema_minor_version], [schema_extended_info] FROM [schema_info]

... (same for all other tables in scope (repeted from "Dropping Tracking Table..."))

INFO   , Deleting Scope Info entry '1027_SyncScope'
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: DELETE [scope_info] WHERE [sync_scope_name] = @scopeName
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @scopeName Len: 14 Value: 1027_SyncScope
INFO   , Adding Scope Info entry for '1027_SyncScope'
INFO   ,    UserComment: 
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: INSERT INTO [scope_info] ([sync_scope_name], [scope_config_id], [scope_timestamp], [scope_user_comment]) VALUES (@scopeName, @configId , 1, @userDesc)
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @scopeName Len: 14 Value: 1027_SyncScope
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @configId Value: b8568957-a533-4a85-9cb6-d49be9012ef5
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @userDesc Value: 
INFO   , Adding Scope Config Entry for config id 'b8568957-a533-4a85-9cb6-d49be9012ef5'
VERBOSE,    Executing Command: INSERT INTO [scope_config] ([config_id], [config_data]) VALUES (@configId, @configData)
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @configId Value: b8568957-a533-4a85-9cb6-d49be9012ef5
VERBOSE,       Parameter: @configData Len: 8177 Value: <SqlCeSyncProviderScopeConfiguration xmlns:xsi="ht...
INFO   , --- END Provisioning Scope '1027_SyncScope' on Database 'TEstMC.sdf' ---
```

And then the sync itself starts

[Here is a GIST with the code.](https://gist.github.com/tb2johhm/61dcf30da597c4537a76#file-program-cs)

Comment: What OS are the devices?

Comment: can you post your provisioning code? a sync shouldn't be dropping tables. the only time the tracking tables are created/removed are on provisioning/deprovisioning.

Comment: @ErikEJ: Actually the device is a windows computer running standard Win7...

Comment: @JuneT: I don't run the provisioning code during sync, and I'm not a 100% sure it really removes the tables, however the entry after the first sync is removed during the second. And I have also managed to add some logging, and the logs starts with (or at least very early in the process) "Dropping table..." (don't have the logs at this moment).

Comment: try enabling Sync Fx logging in Verbose mode

Comment: can you add snippets of your provisioning code?

Comment: ok. i understand better now. ignoring the DROP/CREATE on the tracking tables for now, even if it doesn't recreate the tracking table. you'd still encounter the same issue. the info on what has been synched is stored with the scope. the tracking tables are simply for tracking changes, not what has been synched. what has beens synched by one scope is not visible to another scope. so in you scenario, what has been synched by the 1st scope is not known to the 2nd scope. if row happens to have been downloaded by scope1, scope2 doesn't know about it and will download it again if it picks it up.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it seem to be, so then the sync framework doesn't fulfill my demands (in minimizing traffic)...
Thanks anyways...